# Conditionally skipping entire line with just fscanf

Tags: c

Need to skip entire line (comment) if the first character is #

Some solutions in other posts suggested `fgets`
but in my case `fscanf` is the preferred option as I need to parse each word 1 by 1 later. How can this be done with just `fscanf` ?
Thank you.

**File to be read**

```
#This line is a comment <== skip this entire line
BEGIN { 
   THIS IS A WORD
}
```

**CODE**

```
void read_file(FILE *file_pointer, Program *p)
{
    char buffer[FILESIZE];
    int count = 0;
    while (fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == '#')
        {
            continue; <============ need to skip until the end of the line
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(p->wds[count++], buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `%s` format for `scanf` reads a *space delimited* string. To read a whole line use `fgets`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He only wants to read one word at a time.

Comment: "I need to parse each word 1 by 1 later." is a reason *for* fgets, not against.

Comment: This is not clear: “`fscanf` is the preferred option as I need to parse each word 1 by 1 later.” If the suggests about `fgets` were that you first read a line with `fgets` and then parse its contents, then, yes, you have to do a bit of finagling with the buffer filled by `fgets` to parse the words out of it. That could be done with `sscanf`, which lets you parse a string already read from a stream. But, if you want to start reading a line with `fscanf` so that you just get one word, then you do not need to use only `fscanf` once you have decided to skip a line.…

Comment: … After seeing a line starts with “#”, you could use `fgets`, `fscanf`, or `getchar` to skip the rest of the line. You should clarify particularly why you think you need to use only `fscanf`.

Comment: An all-`fscanf` solution is going go be difficult, because the scanf family is pretty much exclusively stream-based, and treats all whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) interchangeably.  `fscanf` with a `%s` specifier can do a great job of reading "words" from a file without regard for line boundaries.  But once you've found a `#`, and you want to read/discard from there to the next `\n`, `fscanf` provides no good, clean way to do that.

Comment: You might be able to use `%[…]`, or `%c` in a tight loop, but the code will probably be ugly, not clean like you thought you wanted when you strove for an all-`fscanf` solution.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some solutions in other posts suggested fgets but in my case fscanf is the preferred option as I need to parse each word 1 by 1 later. How can this be done with just fscanf ?

I recommend that you use `fgets` to read a whole line and then you can use `sscanf` instead of `fscanf` to read that line word by word.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_file( FILE *file_pointer )
{
    char line[100];

    while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, file_pointer) != NULL )
    {
        char *p = line;
        char word[50];
        int chars_read;

        //skip line if it starts with "#"
        if ( line[0] == '#' )
        {
            continue;
        }

        //read all words on the line one by one
        while ( sscanf( p, "%49s%n", word, &chars_read ) == 1 )
        {
            //do something with the word
            printf( "Found word: %s\n", word );

            //make p point past the end of the word
            p += chars_read;
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    //this function can also be called with an opened file,
    //however for simplicity, I will simply pass "stdin"
    read_file( stdin );
}
```

With the input

```
This is a test.
#This line should be ignored.
This is another test.
```

this program has the following output:

```
Found word: This
Found word: is
Found word: a
Found word: test.
Found word: This
Found word: is
Found word: another
Found word: test.
```

As you can see, the line starting with the `#` was successfully skipped.

Answer (score 2):

> How can this be done with just `fscanf`?

`fscanf(stdin, "%*[^\n]");` will read all characters other than a new-line character, until an error or end-of-file occurs.

`*` says to suppress assignment of the data being read.

By default, `[` starts a list of characters to accept. However, `^` negates that; `[^\n]` says to accept all characters other than a new-line character.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` after you've read the first word to read the rest of the line.

```
    while (fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == '#')
        {
            fgets(file_pointer, buffer, sizeof buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(p->wds[count++], buffer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This cannot skip the entire line, the words in the first line ("is a line") will be copied as well

Comment: No they won't. `fscanf()` will just read `#This`, and `fgets()` will read `line is a comment`